# Genexus 15 U4 - Preview de Objeto Query + MySQL 64bits

Tags: genexus

Ao clicar na guia Preview do Objeto Query, retorna o erro:

**Can not display the preview of the query:

Type:GeneXus.Data.GxADODataException.Foi feita uma tentativa de se carregar um programa com um formato incorreto. (Exceção de HRESULT: 0x8007000B)**

Segue trecho do client.log obtido em: C:\ProgramData\GeneXus\GeneXus\15\QueryPreview

```
21:46:38,606 [3] DEBUG Genexus.Configuration.Config - DOMConfigurator log4net configured with web.config
21:46:38,621 [3] DEBUG Genexus.Configuration.Config - GxClasses version:15.0.4.113785
21:46:38,643 [3] DEBUG Genexus.Application.GxContext - GxContext.Ctr Default handle:1
21:46:38,663 [3] DEBUG GeneXus.Data.ADO.GxConnectionManager - GxConnectionManager.NewConnection   handle: 1, datasource:Default
21:46:38,734 [3] DEBUG Genexus.Application.GXFileWatcher - DeleteFiles C:\ProgramData\GeneXus\GeneXus\15\QueryPreview\PublicTempStorage\
21:46:38,735 [3] DEBUG Genexus.Configuration.Preferences - BLOB_PATH:C:\ProgramData\GeneXus\GeneXus\15\QueryPreview\PublicTempStorage\
21:46:38,736 [3] DEBUG GeneXus.Data.ADO.GxConnection - Setting IsolationLevel : Read Commited
21:46:39,199 [3] DEBUG GeneXus.Resources.GXResourceManager - FindResources C:\ProgramData\GeneXus\GeneXus\15\QueryPreview\bin\messages.eng.dll
21:46:39,257 [3] WARN  Genexus.Application.GxContext - Could not set Cache Control Http Header Value 'no-cache, no-store' to HttpResponse
21:46:39,324 [3] DEBUG Genexus.Application.GxContext - AbsoluteUri dynamicport:http://localhost:52024/QueryPreview/queryviewer.aspx
21:46:39,345 [3] DEBUG GeneXus.Data.ADO.GxConnectionManager - RemoveConnection   handle 1,datasource:Default
21:46:39,383 [3] DEBUG GeneXus.Http.GXHttpHandler - HttpHeaders: Cache-Control:no-cacheConnection:Keep-AliveContent-Length:764Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencodedAccept:image/gif, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-application, application/xaml+xml, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflateAccept-Language:pt-BRCookie:GX_CLIENT_ID=db1daaa8-0c43-4ead-a3e6-f391f0103647; GX_SESSION_ID=LEKn9U6uVzncnSe4kP%2bg1WQjWR0gsjpK0a5t8atYhrw%3dHost:localhost:52024User-Agent:Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Tablet PC 2.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
HttpCookies: 
GX_CLIENT_ID:db1daaa8-0c43-4ead-a3e6-f391f0103647
GX_SESSION_ID:LEKn9U6uVzncnSe4kP%2bg1WQjWR0gsjpK0a5t8atYhrw%3d
21:46:39,383 [3] DEBUG Genexus.Application.GxContext - AbsoluteUri dynamicport:http://localhost:52024/QueryPreview/queryviewer.aspx
21:46:40,028 [3] DEBUG Genexus.Application.GxContext - GxContext.Ctr Default handle:2
21:46:40,028 [3] DEBUG GeneXus.Data.ADO.GxConnectionManager - GxConnectionManager.NewConnection   handle: 2, datasource:Default
21:46:40,028 [3] DEBUG GeneXus.Data.ADO.GxConnection - Setting IsolationLevel : Read Commited
21:46:40,042 [3] DEBUG GeneXus.Data.ADO.GxConnectionManager - RemoveConnection   handle 2,datasource:Default
21:46:40,045 [3] DEBUG GeneXus.Http.GXHttpHandler - HttpHeaders: Cache-Control:no-cacheConnection:Keep-AliveContent-Length:0Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencodedAccept:*/*Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflateAccept-Language:pt-BRCookie:GX_CLIENT_ID=db1daaa8-0c43-4ead-a3e6-f391f0103647; GX_SESSION_ID=LEKn9U6uVzncnSe4kP%2bg1WQjWR0gsjpK0a5t8atYhrw%3d; ASP.NET_SessionId=jg1jji45aywwtcodo1hirgt2Host:localhost:52024Referer:http://localhost:52024/QueryPreview/queryviewer.aspxUser-Agent:Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Tablet PC 2.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
HttpCookies: 
GX_CLIENT_ID:db1daaa8-0c43-4ead-a3e6-f391f0103647
GX_SESSION_ID:LEKn9U6uVzncnSe4kP%2bg1WQjWR0gsjpK0a5t8atYhrw%3d
ASP.NET_SessionId:jg1jji45aywwtcodo1hirgt2
21:46:40,045 [3] DEBUG Genexus.Application.GxContext - AbsoluteUri dynamicport:http://localhost:52024/QueryPreview/agxpl_getrecordsetcachekey.aspx?1493776000022
21:46:40,051 [2] DEBUG Genexus.Application.GXFileWatcher - TIMEOUT (from system.web/httpRuntime ExecutionTimeout)110 seconds
21:46:40,057 [3] DEBUG Genexus.Application.GxContext - GxContext.Ctr Default handle:3
21:46:40,057 [3] DEBUG GeneXus.Data.ADO.GxConnectionManager - GxConnectionManager.NewConnection   handle: 3, datasource:Default
21:46:40,057 [3] DEBUG GeneXus.Data.ADO.GxConnection - Setting IsolationLevel : Read Commited
21:46:40,235 [3] DEBUG GeneXus.Data.ADO.GxConnectionManager - RemoveConnection   handle 3,datasource:Default
21:46:40,236 [3] DEBUG GeneXus.Http.GXHttpHandler - HttpHeaders: Cache-Control:no-cacheConnection:Keep-AliveContent-Length:946Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencodedAccept:*/*Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflateAccept-Language:pt-BRCookie:GX_CLIENT_ID=db1daaa8-0c43-4ead-a3e6-f391f0103647; GX_SESSION_ID=LEKn9U6uVzncnSe4kP%2bg1WQjWR0gsjpK0a5t8atYhrw%3d; ASP.NET_SessionId=jg1jji45aywwtcodo1hirgt2Host:localhost:52024Referer:http://localhost:52024/QueryPreview/queryviewer.aspxUser-Agent:Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Tablet PC 2.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
HttpCookies: 
GX_CLIENT_ID:db1daaa8-0c43-4ead-a3e6-f391f0103647
GX_SESSION_ID:LEKn9U6uVzncnSe4kP%2bg1WQjWR0gsjpK0a5t8atYhrw%3d
ASP.NET_SessionId:jg1jji45aywwtcodo1hirgt2
21:46:40,236 [3] DEBUG Genexus.Application.GxContext - AbsoluteUri dynamicport:http://localhost:52024/QueryPreview/agxpl_getmetadata.aspx?1493776000047
21:46:40,243 [3] DEBUG Genexus.Application.GxContext - GxContext.Ctr Default handle:4
21:46:40,243 [3] DEBUG GeneXus.Data.ADO.GxConnectionManager - GxConnectionManager.NewConnection   handle: 4, datasource:Default
21:46:40,243 [3] DEBUG GeneXus.Data.ADO.GxConnection - Setting IsolationLevel : Read Commited
21:46:40,350 [3] DEBUG Genexus.Application.GxContext - GxContext.Ctr Default handle:5
21:46:40,351 [3] DEBUG GeneXus.Data.ADO.GxConnectionManager - GxConnectionManager.NewConnection   handle: 5, datasource:Default
21:46:40,351 [3] DEBUG GeneXus.Data.ADO.GxConnection - Setting IsolationLevel : Read Commited
21:46:40,360 [3] DEBUG GeneXus.Data.NTier.DataStoreProvider - Start DataStoreProvider.Ctr, Parameters: handle '5', dataStoreHelper:QueryViewer.Services.dsHelper
21:46:40,365 [3] DEBUG GeneXus.Data.ADO.GxCommand - GxCommand.FetchSize: 100, handle '5'
21:46:40,369 [3] DEBUG GeneXus.Data.NTier.DataStoreProvider - gxObject:QueryViewer.Services.dsHelper, handle '5' cursorName:gxpl0001
21:46:40,375 [3] DEBUG GeneXus.Data.ADO.GxCommand - ExecuteReader: Parameters 
21:46:40,378 [3] DEBUG GeneXus.Data.GxMySql - ExecuteReader: client cursor=False, handle '5', hashcode 28123475 PreparedStmt True
21:46:40,381 [3] DEBUG GeneXus.Data.ADO.GxConnection - Start GxConnection.Open, autoCommit=False handle:5 datastore:Default
21:46:40,387 [3] DEBUG GeneXus.Data.GxMySql - MAX_TRIES=100
21:46:40,387 [3] DEBUG GeneXus.Data.GxMySql - Setting connectionString property Location=localhost;Port=3306;;User ID=root;Password=xxxxx;Data Source=CoopHortaDES;
21:46:40,392 [3] ERROR GeneXus.Data.MySqlConnectionWrapper - Return GxConnection.Open Error 
System.BadImageFormatException: Foi feita uma tentativa de se carregar um programa com um formato incorreto. (Exceção de HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
   em MySQLDriverCS.CPrototypes.mysql_init(Void* must_be_null)
   em MySQLDriverCS.MySQLConnection.Open()
   em GeneXus.Data.MySqlConnectionWrapper.Open()
21:46:40,432 [3] DEBUG GeneXus.Data.GxMySql - ProcessError: dbmsErrorCode=0, emsg 'Foi feita uma tentativa de se carregar um programa com um formato incorreto. (Exceção de HRESULT: 0x8007000B)'
21:46:40,433 [3] ERROR GeneXus.Data.ADO.GxConnection - GxConnection.Open Error 
Type:GeneXus.Data.GxADODataException.Foi feita uma tentativa de se carregar um programa com um formato incorreto. (Exceção de HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
21:46:40,433 [3] ERROR GeneXus.Data.ADO.GxCommand - Return GxCommand.ExecuteReader Error 
Type:GeneXus.Data.GxADODataException.Foi feita uma tentativa de se carregar um programa com um formato incorreto. (Exceção de HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
21:46:40,433 [3] DEBUG GeneXus.Data.GxMySql - ProcessError: dbmsErrorCode=0, emsg 'Foi feita uma tentativa de se carregar um programa com um formato incorreto. (Exceção de HRESULT: 0x8007000B)'
21:46:40,458 [3] ERROR GeneXus.Data.ADO.GxCommand - GxCommand.FetchData Error 
21:46:40,462 [3] DEBUG GeneXus.Data.ADO.GxConnection - UncommitedChanges before Close:False
21:46:40,463 [3] DEBUG GeneXus.Data.ADO.GxConnection - GxConnection.Close connection is closed 
21:46:40,464 [3] DEBUG GeneXus.Data.ADO.GxConnectionManager - RemoveConnection   handle 5,datasource:Default
21:46:40,464 [3] DEBUG GeneXus.Data.ADO.GxConnection - UncommitedChanges before Close:False
21:46:40,464 [3] DEBUG GeneXus.Data.ADO.GxConnection - GxConnection.Close connection is closed 
21:46:40,478 [3] DEBUG Genexus.Application.GxContext - GxContext.Ctr Default handle:6
21:46:40,478 [3] DEBUG GeneXus.Data.ADO.GxConnectionManager - GxConnectionManager.NewConnection   handle: 6, datasource:Default
21:46:40,478 [3] DEBUG GeneXus.Data.ADO.GxConnection - Setting IsolationLevel : Read Commited
21:46:40,483 [3] DEBUG GeneXus.Data.ADO.GxConnectionManager - RemoveConnection   handle 4,datasource:Default
21:46:40,483 [3] DEBUG GeneXus.Http.GXHttpHandler - HttpHeaders: Cache-Control:no-cacheConnection:Keep-AliveContent-Length:866Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencodedAccept:*/*Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflateAccept-Language:pt-BRCookie:GX_CLIENT_ID=db1daaa8-0c43-4ead-a3e6-f391f0103647; GX_SESSION_ID=LEKn9U6uVzncnSe4kP%2bg1WQjWR0gsjpK0a5t8atYhrw%3d; ASP.NET_SessionId=jg1jji45aywwtcodo1hirgt2Host:localhost:52024Referer:http://localhost:52024/QueryPreview/queryviewer.aspxUser-Agent:Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Tablet PC 2.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
HttpCookies: 
GX_CLIENT_ID:db1daaa8-0c43-4ead-a3e6-f391f0103647
GX_SESSION_ID:LEKn9U6uVzncnSe4kP%2bg1WQjWR0gsjpK0a5t8atYhrw%3d
ASP.NET_SessionId:jg1jji45aywwtcodo1hirgt2
21:46:40,483 [3] DEBUG Genexus.Application.GxContext - AbsoluteUri dynamicport:http://localhost:52024/QueryPreview/agxpl_getdata.aspx?1493776000239
21:46:40,486 [9] DEBUG GeneXus.Data.ADO.GxConnectionManager - RemoveConnection   handle 6,datasource:Default
```

Answer (score 1):

Boa noite, consegui. Acredito tem alguns pontos que podemos pensar a respeito.

1º. o link no WIKI que aponta para o conector de 64bits, ao meu entender, aponta para o download errado, pois fiz o download, peguei a dll em SysWOW64, e não funcionou. Pesquisando no site do Mysql, fui ao conector [mysql-connector-c-6.1.10-winx64.zip](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=470337) . Fiz o download e o dll funcionou. Então, não seria o caso de atualizar o wiki?

2º. Se o GeneXus distribui o WebDev.WebServer2 64bits, porque não trazer logo a dll 64bits no install?!

Bom, de qualquer forma, valeu as dicas!
Alguem pode marcar como resolvido?

Answer (score 0):

Claudio,

Na pasta C:\ProgramData\GeneXus\GeneXus\15\QueryPreview\bin provavelmente terá a .dll do MySQL, chamada MySQLDriverCS.dll. Tente substituí-la pela dll de 64-bits.

Comment: Então, mas nao encontrei a MySQLDriverCS.dll de 64bits.... no projeto, que tem o link no wiki, não tem.

Comment: Claudio,

Segundo informações da própria GeneXus, os drivers 64-bits podem ser baixados de: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=382641

Fonte: http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?2041,MySQL+driver+for+.NET+installation,

Answer (score 0):

A mensagem de error esta indicando que a versão do driver não esta certa (32 vs 64 bits).

O preview do Query utiliza um web server chamado WebDev.WebServer2, ele pode ser 32 ou 64 bits. Tem que ver qual versão você tem desse web server (o GeneXus distribui a versão 64 bits). Nesse caso tem que se colocar na pasta C:\ProgramData\GeneXus\GeneXus\15\GXplorer\Preview\bin o driver 64 bits para Mysql.

No [SAC #40940](https://www.genexus.com/developers/websac?es,0,,40940;;) tem informação complementar.